# Type traits doesn't work

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

This:

```
cout << std::is_const<const int*>::value;
```

prints out false and I'd think that it should print true. Why does it print false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, what you have is a *non-const* pointer to a `const int`. You are asking if the *pointer* is const, and it isn't, it can be changed. It just points to something which is const. If you want to know if the pointed-to type is const, something like this should work:

```
std::is_const<std::iterator_traits<const int*>::value_type>::value;
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Um, missing a `typename` where?

Comment: @Charles: Before `std::iterator_traits<…>::value_type`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Even if this appeared in a template definition, I don't see a dependent type. Of course, as it stands it could be replaced with `true` so presumably the idea is that `const int*` is replaced by something that would be a dependent type.

Answer (score 9):

Because `const int *` is a *variable* pointer to a *constant integer*.

`std::is_const< int * const >::value` is `true` because the type is a constant pointer to a variable integer. The `const` binds to whatever precedes it, unless it is first in the type specifier. I avoid putting it first to avoid invoking this "special rule."

Constant pointers are usually represented by references in C++.

To get information about the type pointed to, use `std::remove_pointer`.

```
std::is_const< typename std::remove_pointer< const int * >::type >::value
```

is `true`.

Comment: @Potatoswater yes, but isn't the 'question' of a type, that is isn't the type pointed by const? And if not how can I do it with std tools?

Comment: @There: In your example, the type pointed *to* is const. The pointer itself may be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Because pointer to constant is not constant. You probably wanted `cout << std::is_const<int *const>::value;` (constant pointer to int)

Comment: no I wanted what I've typed. I want to know if the type pointed to is const.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do : In this case you should stick to Potatoswatter 's solution.